# How do I make multiple instances of scrollable text? It Works for one instance

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am building a functionality in javascript by which if a class is applied to a span, it scrolls to the left.

[Link to the scrolling text code on codepen](http://codepen.io/rickieanand/pen/YWJWqR)

```
            <htm>
            <head>
            <style type="text/css">

            *{margin: 0;padding: 0}

            pre {
              overflow: auto;
            }

            .frmText{
                width: 300px;
                height: 32px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .scrollable{
            white-space: pre;

            }
            </style>
            <script> 

                var tt=setTimeout("",100);

                var scrollable, ele, text, newText, str, id;
                function scrollText(){
                    text = ele.innerHTML;
                    newText = text.substr(0,1);
                    str= text.substr(1,text.length) + newText;
                    ele.innerHTML = str;
                    console.log("----"+ele.innerHTML)
                    tt=setTimeout("scrollText()",100);
                }

                window.onload = function() {

                    scrollable = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable');

                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(scrollable, function(el, i){
                        ele= el;
                        id= i;
                        ele.innerHTML+='               '
                        try {
                            scrollText();                
                        }
                        catch(e){

                        }
                        console.log("**********************************************")
                    });

                }

                function stop(){
                    window.clearTimeout(tt);
                }
            </script>
            </head>

            <body>


            <div class=frmText>
                <p class='scrollable' onmouseover="stop()" onmouseout="scrollText()">Batman vs Superman scrolling text scrollTexts here</p>
                <p class='scrollable' onmouseover="stop()" onmouseout="scrollText()">Superman vs Batman scrolling text starts here</p>

            </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

The problem is it doesn't work for multiple instances.
I guess the only option left is to go for multithreading
I want this code purely in javascript.

Kindly help

Comment: Use marquee for auto scroll div, no need to write any js , just HTML handle it http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquees.htm

Comment: I'd advise against marquee because it is obsolete and browser support is not guaranteed.

Comment: As I said earlier, I want to implement it using Javascript only and all the elements having class scrollable should scroll. Marquee is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more prudent to use text-indent on your element along with CSS transition.

Animate the text-indent property;
When text-indent reaches negative element width, reset text-indent to 0px;
Set animation-iteration-count: infinite;

Comment: Thanks but as soon as the text goes out of the container, the text must appear to the right such that I can see both, the previous and the next text at the same time. This experience cannot be replicated using your way